# How to update order of dictionary to last while appending

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionary

Primary = `[{'emptype': ['Manager'], 'Designation': ['Developer']}]`

If I update primary with   `'projecttype': ['temp']`

The new dictionary will be `[{'emptype': ['Manager'], 'Designation': ['Developer'],'projecttype': ['temp'] }]`

- You can see 'projecttype': ['temp'] updated to last

If I keep on appending the values My updated key has to go to last part

Example `emptype` is updated with 'Associate'

`[{'Designation': ['Developer'],'projecttype': ['temp'], 'emptype': ['Manager', 'Associate']}]`

- You can see `emptype` updated to last part.

I m using python version 3.8. So order of dictionary is preserved.

Basically if any addition in keys or adding in values those dictionary will goes to last part. How to achieve this
?

Comment: Are you aware that ``Primary_dictionary`` is a *list of* a dictionary?

Comment: Please share your attempt.

Comment: Will all values be lists?

Comment: @LakshyaRaj yes all the values will be list

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Actually, what is even your question?

Comment: You can always manually re-order a key by popping and re-inserting it, e.g. ``p['emptype'] = p.pop('emptype')``. However, the dictionary type has no knowledge about the content of its values being modified, so it cannot trigger this automatically.

Comment: @smac89 i have a list of dictionary, if any new key got added then it has to got last part,  likely if value got added/changed of a key then that key will got to last part

Comment: Also you can't _append_ values to a dictionary. Append is a verb associated with lists. So when you keep saying _append_ yet you have a dictionary inside a list, it is very confusing if you are talking about the dictionary or the list.

Comment: @smac89 append by means `update`

Comment: "append by means ``update``" – your question implies append means append *to a value that is a list*. Please clarify which is it.

Comment: I can't get where is a problem? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @hidden  My achieve is any new insertion of key or new insertion/ change of value those will go to last part of the list of dictionary,

Comment: @Maws, I believe you want to do what **MisterMiyagi** suggested - pop the element, update it, and then update your dictionary with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

@JLeno46 had a great answer, but the solution was a little off of being completely working.  Here is a function that will work for both inserting a key and updating a key:

```py
def update(key, val):
    x = Primary[0].pop(key, [])
    x.append(val)
    Primary[0][key] = x
```

This function can update and create new keys, and is `KeyError`-proof.

Notes:

1. It uses only one key and one value.  This way, it doesn't need to ignore anything.
2. It only works for `Primary`.  You can add a list of a dictionary parameter to make it work for all lists of dictionaries.
3. Already said, but `Primary` is a list of a dictionary.  You might want it to be just a dictionary.  Just replace `Primary[0]` with `Primary`, and remove the `[]` from the declaration of `Primary`.

---

(Before Edit) Try this:

```py
Primary = [{'emptype': ['Manager'], 'Designation': ['Developer']}]
def update(newPair):
    key = list(newPair.keys())[0]
    if key in Primary[0].keys():
        val = Primary[0].pop(key, None)
        val.append(list(newPair.values())[0])
        Primary[0][key] = val
    else:
        Primary[0][key] = [list(newPair.values())[0]]

# Test it
print(Primary[0])
update({'projecttype': 'temp'})
print(Primary[0])
update({'emptype': 'Dev'})
print(Primary[0])
```

**Notes:**

*1.* You can only `update()` 1 item at a time.  Passing a `list` will get this:

```
update('projecttype': ['temp', 'helper'])

Primary is now:
[{'emptype': ['Manager'], 'Designation': ['Developer'], 'projecttype': [['temp', 'helper']]}]
```

which has `[['temp', 'helper']]` instead of `['temp', 'helper']`.

*2.* You must pass a dictionary with only one key.  That's basically a list, but to go along with dictionaries it was made that way.  If you have more than one key, only the 0th key will be used, the other ignored.

*3.* As @MisterMiyagi has said, `Primary` is a *list  of a dictionary*.  If you have just noticed this, you can remove the `[]` from `Primary` and replace all `Primary[0]` to `Primary`.

Answer (score 1):

```
primary = [{'emptype': ['Manager'], 'Designation': ['Developer'],'projecttype': ['temp']}]

x = primary[0].pop('emptype')
x.append('Associate')
primary[0].update({'emptype': x})

print(primary)
```

output:

```
[{'Designation': ['Developer'], 'projecttype': ['temp'], 'emptype': ['Manager', 'Associate']}]
```

or you can use a func like this:

```
def update_last(my_dict, key, new_value):
    x = dict.pop(key)
    x.append(new_value)
    my_dict.update({key: x})
    return my_dict
```

Comment: This suffers from the problem that when `pop` isn't passed a second value, it will `raise KeyError`.  Passing a second value will return it when the key isn't found.  A `try except` statement might help when trying to `pop` the (possibly) non-existent value, like `try: x = dict.pop(key) except KeyError: pass`

Comment: Yeah, but of course I'm assuming he's not gonna pop a non-existing key, this is just a schema with the basic steps, @Maws should take care of a more complex implementation based on his needs.

Comment: What I meant is that when you try inserting a new key (like `update_last(Primary, 'id', 'test')`), it will try to pop `id`, but `id` does not exist, causing `KeyError` [(refer here)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-pop-method/).  Therefore, you should try catching that possible exception before continuing.  Otherwise, you answer is really good!

Comment: If he needs to add a new key at the end, .update works already fine. The problem is when updating an existing key.

Comment: So your first piece of code is to insert a new key, and your second (the third code block) is to update an existing key?  I'm sorry, I thought that `update_last` was a globally working function, meaning working for inserting a new key, and updating an already existing key.  A suggestion: you might want to make a single function for this.  And to [this comment of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65051966/how-to-update-order-of-dictionary-to-last-while-appending/65052398?noredirect=1#comment115007348_65052398), I was able to successfully update an existing key with your function.

Comment: It's the same code, I just put it inside a func in the second block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225282/discussion-between-lakshya-raj-and-jleno46).